# Rsepc Validation Testing with custom validations: undefined method and nil class error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, rspec, shoulda

I have a simple model where payment belongs to loan. And I am using rspec and shoulda-matcher to test validations. However I kept receiving errors pointing to outstanding balance -- indicating it is an undefined method for nil class. But this validation is working when I am playing with the models in rails console. Anyone knows why it is failing the test???

Thanks.

```
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :loan

  validates_presence_of :loan_id
  validate :proper_amount

  private

  def proper_amount
    errors.add(:amount, "proper") if amount > loan.outstanding_balance
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :payment do
    loan
    amount 100.0
    post_at Date.today
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :loan do
    funded_amount 5000.0
  end
end

RSpec.describe Payment do

  before (:all) do
    @loan = FactoryGirl.create(:loan)
    @payment = FactoryGirl.create(:payment, loan: @loan)
  end

  describe 'ActiveModel validations' do

    #basic validations on attributes
    it { should validate_presence_of(:loan_id) }
  end
end

Failure/Error: it { should validate_presence_of(:amount) }
NoMethodError:
  undefined method `outstanding_balance' for nil:NilClass
```

Answer (score 0):

Shoulda matchers uses the subject, which you've not set.  So as I understand RSpec will initialize one.

```
RSpec.describe Payment do

  let!(:loan){ FactoryGirl.create(:loan) }
  subject!(:payment){ FactoryGirl.create(:payment, loan: loan) }

  describe 'ActiveModel validations' do

    #basic validations on attributes
    it { should validate_presence_of(:loan_id) }
  end
end
```

Now, rather than use @loan and @payment you'd need to use loan and payment in your other tests.

Comment: Thanks! I did what you said and had the same error...Any thoughts?

Comment: What is in your factory_girl load and payment definitions?  Maybe add explanation marks to `let!` and `subject!` so RSpec doesn't create them lazily

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. I have added in my factory girl code. Factories are working fine in other tests. I have tried to to inspect factory girl instance variable and the output looks fine as well. What do you mean by add explanation marks?

Comment: Sorry, I meant exclamation.

Comment: Hi I figured out the problem. add return unless amount && loan_id in the proper_amount method. But ! also helped me in other places. Thanks still!